# How to NOT copy text formatting in photoshop from a text layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, layers

I'm using Photoshop.
I want to **copy text** from a layer in one document and **paste in a layer in second document** without changing the formatting in the second layer.
What happen is that the text formatting also gets copied with the text and when I paste it in the other layer its formatting changes according to the copied layer. I just want to **copy the text only.**
Nobody seems to be asking this question.
I have some screenshot to illustrate my point.

Steps:

1. Copy the text "Lorem Ipsum"
2. Select the layer "Team Working
   dedicatedly."
3. Paste the text.

You can see that the font of the title layer changes to the font of the body text layer.

[image: Copy the text "Lorem Ipsum"]
[image: Select the title layer]

[image: Paste the text there]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit menu > Paste Special > Paste without formatting

Or right click menu > Paste without formatting

[image]

---

[image]

---

You can hot-key it, as with any Adobe menu item, from Edit menu > Keyboard shortcuts…

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: On many word processors, there is a shortcut like CTRL+SHIFT+C, which does the same. Is there an equivalent for Photoshop?

Comment: I've never known a copy without format, only paste without format. You can hot-key any Adobe menu item, so you can make it whatever you wish.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. CTRL+SHIFT+V, not C. My mistake.

Comment: I added the hot-key method

Answer (score 9):

You already have an answer for recent versions of Photoshop, but for versions older than CC 2018 which don't have that option, it's also possible to paste the text into a plain text editor such as Notepad or TextEdit, copy the text again, then paste into Photoshop. This will strip the formatting.

Comment: And if the text is not very long, you can just copy the layer name. Which is what I currently do.

Comment: @NiazKhan Sure. And you could also just paste it into the search bar in a web browser, or even the search bar in Windows 10, or any application that uses plain unformatted text, select all, and copy again, then paste into Photoshop.  There are so many ways to go about this that involve using the same basic principle.